# Listings problem with quotes in a string

Tags: listings, punctuation, highlighting, strings, matlab

A single quote occuring inside a `listings` string seems to be interpreted as ending the string. Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Matlab,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{Blue}\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{Red}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{Emerald}\ttfamily,
        morecomment=[l][\color{Magenta}]{\#},
        breaklines=true,
        breakindent=0pt,
        breakatwhitespace,
        columns=fullflexible,
        showstringspaces=false
}


\begin{lstlisting}
a=1;
if a==1
    disp('Is 1')
elseif a==2
    disp('Is 2')
else
    disp('I don't know')
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because single quotes are used as string delimiters in Matlab, you need to *escape* that character in order to make it part of the string. This is done by typing two single quotes in a row: `disp('I don''t know')`.

Comment: It adds two single quotes in the output. I want the output to have a single quote. If you see the Matlab documentation it uses single quotes.

Comment: Don't you get error when you compile your program in Matlab?

Comment: If what you want to show is the exact Matlab code, then it's correct to show the two single quotes. Can you post a link to the online Matlab help showing two single quotes as one?

Comment: I misread it sorry. Thank you for your help in LaTeX and in Matlab!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because single quotes are used as string delimiters in Matlab, you need to escape that character in order to make it part of the string. This is done by typing two single quotes in a row:

```
disp('I don''t know')
```

The `Matlab` language defined by `listings` is clever enough to typeset the right thing, in this case:

[image]

As a side note, you might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: He will get an error in Matlab if he doesn't do so.

Comment: @user230137 Exactly.

Comment: Ok I get it, thank you very much! In this site I am learning also about Matlab! :P

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution from [listings.pdf](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/start/listings.pdf) with `mathescape` parameter:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}




\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Matlab,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{Blue}\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{Red}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{Emerald}\ttfamily,
        morecomment=[l][\color{Magenta}]{\#},
        breaklines=true,
        breakindent=0pt,
        breakatwhitespace,
        columns=fullflexible,
        showstringspaces=false
}


\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
a=1;
if a==1
    disp('Is 1')
elseif a==2
    disp('Is 2')
else
    disp('I don$\texttt{\color{red}'}$t know')
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do that if you want, but that's very misleading, because it shows incorrect syntax.